# Is there a way to dinamically cast an object into a given type?

Tags: java, xml, object, types, casting

So I have an assignment, in which I'm stuck. The program saves instances of a class into an xml file. Every field has an annotation which tells the simple name of it's type. (Integer, String, Double, etc.) I'm at a part, where I get the values and attributes of every xml tag. I've created an Object, which stores the value of the tag. I want to cast that object into the type given by the xml attribute, but since it's gonna be a string, Java won't let me to do so. I'll copy the part of my code for better understanding.

```
                    for(Integer j = 0; j < tulajdonsagok.getLength(); j++){
                    Node nodee = tulajdonsagok.item(j); //this is the field of the class instance in the xml
                    if(nodee.getNodeType() != Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                    continue;
                        Element tulajdonsag = (Element)nodee;
                        String tulajdonsagNev = tulajdonsag.getNodeName(); //getting the field's name
                        Object adat = (tulajdonsag.getTextContent()); //getting the field's value
                            Attr attr = (Attr)tulajdonsag.getAttributes().getNamedItem("type");
                            //The type attribute is the value type
                            Class<?> cls = Class.forName("java.lang."+attr.getValue());
                    //}
                }
```

And here, if for example the Type is Double, I want to cast my object called "adat" into the given type. But I don't know how, because it's got the text content of the tag, and it automatically becomes a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just cast `String` to `Double` in any case. Instead you need to handle the conversion explicitly. If you know that `adat` is a string you could provide a bunch of converters, e.g. `StringToDoubleConverter`, `StringToIntConverter` etc., select the correct one based on `cls` and pass the string to that converter.

Example:

```
interface StringConverter<T> {
  T parse(String value);
}

class StringToDoubleConverter implements StringConverter<Double> {
   Double parse(String value) {
     //parse here, I'll leave the implementation for you :)
   }
}
```

Then maintain some form of repository and provide a way to get the correct converter. Your code could then do it like this:

```
StringConverter<?> converter = converterRepo.getConverter(cls);
Object parsedValue = converter.parse(adat);
```

Note that you'd have to do some nasty casting at least internally since you can't use "checkable" types here but if you make sure that `getConverter(Double.class)` returns a `StringConverter<Double>` you should be good.

A lot of frameworks do it like that. And btw, why aren't you using one of those, e.g. Jackson or JAXB?

Comment: Well, I looked up what JAXB is (never heard of it unfortunatelly). It would be much more easier. The reason why I'm doing it this way, is because our professor promised a job offer for the person, who can give him the most generic solution. Originally, this is a loading method which can be used onevery class in the program. I'm a bit short on money, and tought I'll give it a try, maybe I can do it. Anyway, thank you, I'll give a try for your solution, think it's gonna solve the problem. Thanks a lot! :)